# How to make SolrCloud use HTTPS for creating collections?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm setting up SolrCloud 7.2.1 on a Windows Server 2016, following the getting started guide: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/getting-started-with-solrcloud.html#GettingStartedwithSolrCloud-InteractiveStartup

I have to specify the host because for some reason the SOLR_HOST variable does not have any effect. localhost gets tried all to time.
So specifying the host, everything works fine until a new collection has to be created.
For some reason I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to create collection 'collectionname' due to: {solrurl:8984_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solrurl:8984/solr, solrurl:8983_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solrurl:8983/solr}
```

I'm a bit puzzled here because I don't understand why it uses HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I can call the URLs with HTTPS without any problems.
When creating a new collection inside the Solr web interface, the same error occures.
SOLR_SSL_ENABLED variable is set to true.

So how can I change this behaviour? Is there anything I have to do beforehand to make Solr accept changes to the solr.in.cmd and solr.in.sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use inter node communcation over SSL, you have to [tell Solr to use that first before bringing the nodes up](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/enabling-ssl.html#configure-zookeeper).

You can use the bundled `zkcli` tool to set the cluster property first:

```
server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd clusterprop -name urlScheme -val https
```